# Can Decepticons communicate wirelessly?

Tags: transformers, transformers-live-action-series

Is it possible that the Decepticons can communicate via wirelessly?

In the first tranformers movie, Megatron awakens from a 200 year frozen sleep, declares his name, and exits the dam. Immediately he says "you've failed me again Starscream" as he passes Starscream. How else could he have known Starscream failed?  Had he already received a progress report from nearby Decepticons? *Unless Starscream is a perpetual failure and Megatron just assumes the worst about him, shame on you Megatron!*

I recall that at least in the cartoons Autobots and Decepticons had different abilities. For instance, all Decepticons had the ability to fly regardless of vehicle type.

Comment: Speaking, of course, doesn’t actually require wires.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From this [transcript](http://www.script-o-rama.com/movie_scripts/a1/transformers-script-transcript.html), the relevant quote from the movie is:

> Starscream: I live to serve you, Lord Megatron.
>
> Megatron: Where is the Cube?
>
> Starscream: The humans have taken it.
>
> Megatron: You fail me yet again, Starscream.

So Starscream gives Megatron the update right there but only after being asked.

I guess the above doesn't really answer the question, however in the comics/cartoon they do communicate wirelessly. In the movie I believe they also communicate wirelessly, at one point I remember one attach itself to a satellite to glean information, and then communicate that to the others.

Answer (score 3):

In the cartoon and the comics the TFs are explicitely shown to be able to communicate wirelessly. Usually it was done through a built in device. In the first live action movie I vaguely recall a Decepticon (don't recall who) talking to Starscream while he was in the air. It was in Cybertronian with English subtitles. Since the two Decepticons weren't near each other that means they were communicating wirelessly.

Comment: They do.  Soundwave spent most of the first two movies in orbit, watching, stealing data off of the satellites and passing information back and forth.

Comment: @BBlake - Yeah I thought about mentioning Soundwave, but I thought that could be attributed to him having a unique ability (as OP mentioned). Since he (and Blaster) seemed to handle communications in the cartoon.

Answer (score -1):

All deceptions communicate wirelessly because they are never in the same place but know what each other are doing.

Comment: What does this add that the accepted answer does not already cover?